# Do the pub names and their order mean anything?

Tags: analysis, the-worlds-end

Seeing as to how the final pub, *The World's End*, is more or less when the world ends, do the other pub names also signify something? What are their names and their positions in the *Golden Mile* crawl?

(I believe that they do mean something. Gary meets Oliver's sister in *The Old Familiar*.)

Comment: I've seen some speculation on some of the pub names - but nothing detailed from the writers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, they do.

As you know, the **Cornetto trilogy** is pretty big on [foreshadowing](http://lolsnaps.com/news/73826/0/).

A fine movie student (posting as guest) got an interesting answer in [edgarwrighthere.com](http://www.edgarwrighthere.com/2013/08/24/the-12-pubs-of-the-golden-mile/) (first comment).

*Italics : comments added by me.*
[...]

> **One. The First Post**
>
> [image]
>
> This pub should be self explanatory, it is the beginning of the
> adventure Gary King (Simon Pegg) and his mates are about to take. The
> sign, itself, adds some depth as one could say that they have come to
> a crossroads with this journey; both paths will eventually lead to the
> prize (completion of the Golden Mile) but the routes will be
> different. To some it may be difficult, and others easy. It's safe to
> say that it was pretty difficult for Gary and Co.
>
> **Two. Old Familiar**
>
> [image]
>
> This pub is where Oliver's (Martin Freeman) sister Sam (Rosamund Pike)
> shows up. Both Gary and Steven (Paddy Considine) had a thing for Sam
> as the group recalls and Gary even tries to become "familiar" with her
> once again in the same pub it happened 20 years earlier.
>
> *Besides the pub is a replica of the first pub.  Note that it ties to the movie main theme: which is things repeating again and again(the reasons varying from nostalgia, arrested development, or clones). And it also describes the benefit of pubs : pubs
> feel safe because they are fundamentally all the same (a bar, taps,
> tables, beer)*
>
> **Three. Famous Cock**
>
> [image]
>
> Gary King and Co. were not allowed to drink in this bar because of the
> events that took place 20 years ago. Gary is trying to seem more
> important (cock of the walk) in this city even though no one remembers
> him. In a sense though he is famous because he is banned from the bar.
>
> *There is a delicious sense of irony there: King wanted desperately to
> be remembered by his old town.
> The only time he is, he's barred from a bar.
> So his wish to be famous denies another wish of his: his bar-athon.
> Another hint at King's current deadlock.*
>
> **Four. Cross Hands**
>
> [image]
>
> Gary and Co. go into this pub, have a few drinks and Co. (Peter,
> Oliver, Steven, and Andy) try to set Gary straight. This pub is where
> a lot of deep emotions come to the surface and everyone suddenly wants
> to become violent (Peter when seeing his old high school bully, Andy
> when he finds out Gary lied, and the whole fight scene in the
> bathroom).
>
> *As noted by [@Nobby](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/382/nobby), the background of the sign is a callback
> to the bathroom tiles where the infamous fight took place.*
>
> **Five. The Good Companion**
>
> [image]
>
> Gary and Co. continue to do the pub crawl but as the sign shows, only
> one (the King himself) is actually having a good time while the others
> only want to continue to save themselves from the robots.
>
> **Six. The Trusty Servant**
>
> [image]
>
> Now, are they really robots? Anyways, we're getting off topic. In this
> pub we see Tyres, I mean Reverend Green and two others warning Gary
> and Co. about the danger that is around them. When Reverend Green says
> too much, he willingly (but not joyfully, hence the sadness of the
> trusty servant) obeys the order of the mysterious beings (as he must)
> and disappears. (Also note that this is the time O-man becomes a
> servant)
>
> **Seven. The Two Headed Dog**
>
> [image]
>
> Now, in this pub Gary and Co. realize that people are acting strange
> (specifically MARK HEAP!!) Using Mark Heap as the bartender may be a
> joke directed at Spaced fans as Brian was never super happy and
> smiling but all of a sudden its his job! We also see the twins change
> and everyone suddenly becomes part supportive of the mission to
> complete the Golden Mile but also try to kill Gary and Co. as well.
> (Note: In the sign there is a dog with two heads, one normal, the
> other with ink on it. This could represent the aliens. They look like
> us, but that does not mean they are)
>
> **Eight. The Mermaid**
>
> [image]
>
> Now this may be a long shot but it makes sense to me, hopefully Edgar
> will agree. I believe this pub is called the Mermaid because of the
> Marmalade Sandwich and their similarities to Odysseus and the Sirens.
> Sirens are often compared to Mermaids. The Sirens enchanting voices
> (sex appeal, in the World's End) would lure soon-to-be-shipwrecked
> sailors for their own benefit (to get their DNA). In this case,
> Steven/Sam was Odysseus and saved their mates from the Sirens. The
> sign is also a Marmalade Mermaid Sandwich.
>
> **Nine. The Beehive**
>
> [image]
>
> Guy Shepherd (1995-2002 James Bond) explains to Gary and Co. the goal
> of the invasion, how they are all like a Beehive; working together to
> create something magnificent. The group understands that when they say
> they're not willing to join, they may get stung (they get into a huge
> brawl).
>
> *Note the presence of the blue paint, ominous sign of the presence
> the network. As seen before in th two headed dogs*
>
> **Ten. The King's Head**
>
> [image]
>
> Gary KING goes insane and despite the danger wants to finish the
> Golden Mile. It's safe to say he is running around like a Cock with
> its Head cut off.
>
> *And he knocks his head against a post - many times - to prove he's human.*
>
> *As noted by [@Nobby](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/382/nobby), the portrait has a striking resemblance to Gary King's head*
>
> **Eleven. The Hole in the Wall**
>
> [image]
>
> Any crashes the car through the pub, thus, making a hole in the wall.
>
> *Do you think the color blue used for the bricks is just random chance?*
>
> **Twelve. The World's End**
>
> [image]
>
> The world ends; fire spreading across the globe as in the sign. This
> makes way for a new dawn, and a new tale.

Comment: That's excellent. If you can, please also insert the pub signs into your answer.

Comment: Terrific answer - thanks for the research. I added the images which I believe makes this a fully rounded and complete answer. It's also worth noting a couple of extra things...
The Cross Hands seems to depict the bathroom floor behind the ink/blood spattered arms of the friends. Nice touch ;)
Is it just me, or does the Trusty Servant look a little bit like O-Man?
It's worth noting just how much the King's Head sign looks like Gary :)
Love this film - it's Wright's 'Grail Quest' film  - look at the characters' names: King, Prince, Chamberlain, Knightly, Page...

Comment: @Nobby thanks for the edits : the answer looks awesome now !